# What is the proper way to create a folder using android MediaSotre API?

Tags: android, android-studio, mediastore

```
val values = ContentValues()
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Documents/NewFolder")
val uri: Uri? = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(volumeName), values)
```

NewFolder successfully created inside Documents.

But the problem is another file also created **inside NewFolder**.
This file's DisplayName is current Epoch time and have no other columns like DateModified or Size.
And this file can only be seen by content resolver query.

```
val cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder)
```

No other file managers can see this file even Android Studio Device File Explorer, and the file disappears after rebooting mobile.
How to avoid this file creating automatically?

Comment: Did you try without a display name column?

Comment: Yea, I attached display name with relative path. But same problem exists. And that invalid file disappears after a reboot.

Comment: You attached display name? What should that be? I suggested to try without.

Comment: My display name is "NewFolder" and my relative path is "/Documents". First I tried these two as display name and relative path. Second I removed display name and relative path= "/Documents/NewFolder".

Comment: `My display name is "NewFolder"` ???? `


`values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "displayName")` ???

Comment: hi sir, thanks for your reply and sorry for my bad english. Now I edited my question. I think the problem is clear. can you please check once?

Comment: The insert()  member is for inserting an entry for a file and as return value you get an uri for a file. With that the side effect can be that a folder is created. You could have started your post telling why you only want to create a folder. And why you want to use the media store for it.

Comment: I'm trying to build a File Explorer using MediaStore.Files

Comment: You still did not tell why you only want to create a folder. You better leave out the option to create a directory then. Or accept as side effect a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val values = ContentValues()

values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Documents/NewFolder")

contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), values)
```

Demo: https://youtu.be/a6Q7IlA_uOs

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I cannot even create the folder in android 11